# Integrate Django CMS into current Django project but use separated two databases

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a already running Django project: **foo_proj**, and I integrated Django cms into this project, so that some pages are containing "**content**" that managed by Django CMS, this was already working.

However, they were using one same database: **foo_db**, i.e.:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'foo_db',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'SecRete!',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '',
  }
}
```

I am not sure whether or not I can separate them, so that their authentication/authorization are totally separated, user can register on foo_proj, but they cannot login to "**/cms**", so that I can control limited user accounts who have edit permission for "**/cms**".

I was trying to use Django [database routes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/multi-db/), code is like below:

```
from django.conf import settings

class foo_projDBRouter(object):
    def is_cms_app(self, app_label):
        return app_label in ['cms', 'reversion']

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if self.is_cms_app(model._meta.app_label):
            return 'cms'
        else:
            return 'foo_proj'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if self.is_cms_app(model._meta.app_label):
            return 'cms'
        else:
            return 'foo_proj'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if not self.is_cms_app(model._meta.app_label):
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, model):
        return True
```

And in my settings:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['foo_proj.db_route.FooProjDBRouter']
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'foo_proj': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'adsk_foo_proj',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'Secret!',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },
    'cms': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'cms',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'Secret!',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

I didn't make it work for me, and I doubt whether this is going to work? Any suggestions on this please?

The goal is to separate the DBs for my foo_proj and django cms, but dynamically render CMS content while user navigating to pages in foo_proj.

Actually on the official documentation page: http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/support-3.0.x/how_to/integrate.html#databases, it mentioned: "**To use django CMS efficiently, we recommend: Creating a separate database for django CMS to use.**", but it seems there is no further detailed information about how to separate the DB.

Answer (score 0):

One issue I sport is in your database configuration, the following is required. (see #REQUIRED)

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},  # REQUIRED
    'foo_proj': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'adsk_foo_proj',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'Secret!',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },
    'cms': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'cms',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'Secret!',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a careless mistake, I just added it back... Still I got error:django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your `allow_relation` method calls `model`, which is undefined. You could use this instead (from Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/)):

```
def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    """
    Allow relations if a model in the auth app is involved.
    """
    if obj1._meta.app_label == 'auth' or \
       obj2._meta.app_label == 'auth':
       return True
    return None
```